# Local Notifications delivering multiple times instead of just one

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I am writing an application and want to include local notifications. I want the notification to deliver at a set time and repeat everyday.

I programmed this into my application, and it does notify the user. However, instead of the user just being notified one time everyday at the set time, the application sends the user 13+ notifications at that set time. The number of notifications is only increasing every day.

How do I fix this issue? I just want the notification to notify the user only once everyday.

Here is my code that I have been using. It is set in the Did Finish Launching with Options of the App Delegate.

```
let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Badge, .Alert, .Sound], categories: nil)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

let title: String = "Read Today's Pulse Habit!"

let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let calendarComponents = NSDateComponents()
calendarComponents.hour = 15
calendarComponents.minute = 30
calendarComponents.second = 0
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
let dateToFire = calendar.dateFromComponents(calendarComponents)

let notification = UILocalNotification()

notification.alertBody = "\(title)"
notification.alertAction = "Read Now"
notification.fireDate = dateToFire
notification.alertTitle = "PULSE"
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1

UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

I've even tried taking out the line that includes the incrementing icon badge number and that did not make any difference.

Comment: Where are you putting this implementation? App delegate has no associated view, and hence no viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Oops. I meant did Finish Launching with Options in the App Delegate.